# ar.js clicking works on pc but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, responsive, augmented-reality, ar.js

I am building a small application with ar.js and everything seems to work on pc but once I try it on my phone I can't seem to be able to click anymore. Everything also ends up being stretched or squashed depending on the rotation of the phone.

I think the not being able to press anything has to do with the stretching/squashing but I don't know how I should fix such an issue?

Currently, the js looks like this

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('interactable-object', 
{
  init: function ()
  {
      var el = this.el;
      el.addEventListener('click', (e) =>
      {
         console.log("item pressed");
      }
  }
}
```

and the Html code like this:

```
<a-entity id='3dmodel' interactable-object position="1 0 -2" scale="5 5 5"
                        obj-model=" obj: url(models/3dmodel.obj);
                                    mtl: url(models/3dmaterial.mtl); ">

</a-entity>
```

I use `cursor: rayOrigin: mouse;` in my a-marker; I don't know if this is the correct one to use for mobile touch either? Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to make the object more responsive?

I'm using ar.js 2.2.1 and aframe 0.9.2.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you need to listen to 'touchstart' also:

```
el.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) =>
```

But the problem i'm facing now is that this doesn't work well on the edges of the screen, if someone knows a workaround let me know.